# Can I use JPA to filter parent by number of children

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have a parent class with a property children as a one-to-many relation. As this example is constructed I assume that one child can have only one parent :-)

```
public class Parent {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, insertable = false, unique = true)
private Long id;

private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")    
private Set<Child> children;

}

public class Child {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, insertable = false, unique = true)
private Long id;


private String name;

@ManyToOne
private Parent parent;

}
```

But now I would like to filter only parents that have for instance 2 children.
What JPA feature I can use to implement this?

A colleague suggested to add a childrenCounter to the parent. But I do not like this possibility because I will have to update this counter every time I change something on the parent and/or child site.

Comment: Depending the size of your database, you could filter using `streams` (e.g. `resultSet.streams.filter(p -> p.children.size == 2)`). Just in case it's a small list returned.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. You need the following JPQL query:

```
select p
from Parent p
where size(p.children) = 2
```